# Named ranges get deprotected when spreadsheet is copied

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Firstly, forgive my bad english and my little knowledge of GAS.

I have an SpreadSheet that will be programmatically copied about 500 times (one copy for each student).
Teachers will fill in the attendance of the students; and parents will be able to view and insert comments.

Deploying code is quite ready, but while testing I have found THIS ISSUE:

In the template, I have named and protected lots of ranges, in order to teachers not to spoil the sheets. If I share the template, solution works. But If I COPY the template, either manually or programmatically, the protection disappeares in the copies, although the named ranges are still there.

For my distress, I have read in another message that range protection cannot be set programmatically, so I will not be able to restore the protection that way.

Any suggestions?

Comment: See [How to duplicate a sheet with protected ranges?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27607651) It is asked in the context of duplicating a sheet (rather than the whole spreadsheet), but the approach to copying protections is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to [check this out.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#setSheetProtection%28PageProtection%29)

It sounds like you have to do a 2 step process: copy the template creating a new sheet and then copy the template permissions to the new sheet. Good luck

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't seem to solve the problem. As far as I have understood, ClassPageProtection only works on sheets, not on ranges inside the seet. I need the teachers to be able to write in some cells, but to prevent them to write in other cells IN THE SAME SHEET. Please, let me know if I am wrong...

Comment: You are correct. The solution is to move the ranges you need to protect to a sheet to which only you have access. [That's usually not as difficult as it sounds.]

Comment: I don't really understand your suggestion. Besides, there are 500 files replicated; any work now should be done programmatically. Anyway, I will survive. Should I mark the question as answered? I don`t know well the rules here...