# How to duplicate a sheet with protected ranges?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have built a template sheet that I will duplicate every week.  I noticed that when I go to duplicate it, none the protected ranges are copied along with it.  Is it possible to use a Google Apps script to copy the exact same protected ranges into the duplicated sheet?  It would save me lots of time every week.

Comment: Are you currently doing this 100% manually, or do you already have some code?

Comment: 100% manually at the moment.

Answer (score 8):

*Note*: A similar question was posted on Web Apps, so I am adapting a part of [my answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/87000) there to the present case.

---

Using `sheet.getProtections` method, you can get the array of protections on a given sheet, and loop over them, creating their analogs on the target sheet. This is somewhat annoying because there seems to be no method to simply clone a protection to another range. (One can change the range of protection, but that would *move* it to the new range, instead of copying.)

So, in the function below I do the following:

1. Get the A1 notation of each protected range with `p.getRange().getA1Notation();`
2. Protect the corresponding range of the target sheet with `p2 = sheet2.getRange(rangeNotation).protect();`
3. Set the [properties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection) of new protection `p2` according to the properties of original protection `p`. This includes removing/adding editors if the protection is not just of the warning type.

```
function duplicateSheetWithProtections() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Template');
  var sheet2 = sheet.copyTo(ss).setName('My Copy'); 
  var protections = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
  for (var i = 0; i < protections.length; i++) {
    var p = protections[i];
    var rangeNotation = p.getRange().getA1Notation();
    var p2 = sheet2.getRange(rangeNotation).protect();
    p2.setDescription(p.getDescription());
    p2.setWarningOnly(p.isWarningOnly());
    if (!p.isWarningOnly()) {
      p2.removeEditors(p2.getEditors());  // remove editors 
      p2.addEditors(p.getEditors());      // except those permitted for original
      // p2.setDomainEdit(p.canDomainEdit()); //  only if using an Apps domain 
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is adjusted code from above which will prompt you for the name of the sheet you would like to copy and what you want the new name to be:

```
function duplicateSheetWithProtections() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var oldSheetName = ui.prompt('Sheet to Copy?');
  var newSheetName = ui.prompt('New Sheet Name?');
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  sheet = ss.getSheetByName(oldSheetName.getResponseText());
  sheet2 = sheet.copyTo(ss).setName(newSheetName.getResponseText()); 
  var protections = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
  for (var i = 0; i < protections.length; i++) {
    var p = protections[i];
    var rangeNotation = p.getRange().getA1Notation();
    var p2 = sheet2.getRange(rangeNotation).protect();
    p2.setDescription(p.getDescription());
    p2.setWarningOnly(p.isWarningOnly());
    if (!p.isWarningOnly()) {
      p2.removeEditors(p2.getEditors());
      p2.addEditors(p.getEditors());
      // p2.setDomainEdit(p.canDomainEdit()); //  only if using an Apps domain 
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to duplicating a sheet with permissions here:

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/86984/in-google-sheets-how-do-i-duplicate-a-sheet-along-with-its-permission/87000#87000

It looks to have solved it, although I am busy with another problem currently of hiding columns with permissions.

Regards

Answer (score -1):

the [Protection class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection) can be used to protect various ranges in the sheet and possibly even better you can protect the whole sheet and then unprotect specific ranges where input is desired.